# Is there a way to bind a specific column in a spreadsheet to a combobox in a GUI [VBA]

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, settings

I'm trying to use a for each loop to dynamically find which column a given populated combo box is pulling data from in an excel worksheet.  There can be more than one combobox searched (i.e find rows where cmb_year = 2018 and cmb_period = 6 and cmb_group = health.  the end goal is to search the raw data for one criteria then search that data (the one we just filtered) for the next criteria and so forth until all conditions are met.

I tried to use the property BoundColumn so the code would immediately recognize which column to look at to see if the information from the worksheet column matched the data in the combobox, but BoundColumn is a property that seems to only be used for multi-columned comboboxes.

```
If WorksheetExists("FilteredSheet") Then

Worksheets("FilteredSheet").Delete


Else

Dim wrksName As String
wrksName = "FilteredSheet"
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = Worksheets.Add(Type:=xlWorksheet)
With ws2
    .Name = wrksName
End With

End If

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet2")


Dim populatedBoxes As New Collection
'finds all combo boxes that are populated
Set populatedBoxes = GetPopulatedThings(Multipage1, "ComboBox")
Dim cb As MSForms.ComboBox
For Each cb In populatedBoxes
'attemps to loop through each combobox to search for values in it's corresponding column in the worksheet
    Call FilterSheet(ws, ws2, cb)
Next

End Sub

Private Function FilterSheet(wrks As Worksheet, pastewrks As Worksheet, cmb As ComboBox) As Worksheet

a = wrks.UsedRange.Rows(wrks.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

For i = 1 To a
    'tries to find the column in a given row that matches where the combobox was originally populated from
    If wrks.Cells(i, cmb.BoundColumn).Value = cmb.Value Then
        wrks.Rows(i).Copy
        pastewrks.Activate
        b = pastewrks.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        pastewrks.Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Worksheets(wrks).Activate
        'pastes to all matching values to a new worksheet
    End If
Next

Application.CutCopyMode = False


Set FilterSheet = pastewrks

End Function
```

I can't use boundcolumn in the for loop located in FilterSheet because when I change the boundcolumn property to anything more than 1, the value of the combobox becomes null (most likely due to it being a single column combobox)

Comment: Thank you for the format fix.  I'm still new to Stackoverflow!

Comment: 1. Use `Option Explicit` at the top of every module. 2. Look into getting arrays from worksheet ranges. This doesn't "bind" them, but will be an easy way to populate the comboboxes.